# Checking if a variable exists within foreach if statement

Tags: php, if-statement

In the below code, when checking foreach(get_sub_field("items") as $x):

How do I check if $x['item_name']; is empty, do this...

```
<?php $food = 23; ?>
<?php while(has_sub_field("menu_items", $food)): ?>
<?php if(get_row_layout() == 'food_items'): ?>
<?php if (get_sub_field('category')){?>
<h2>
  <?php the_sub_field('category');?>
</h2>
<?php } ?>
<div>
  <?php if(get_sub_field("items")): ?>
  <?php foreach(get_sub_field("items") as $x): ?>
  <div> <?php echo $x['item_name']; ?> <?php echo $x['item_price']; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
  </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Why the hell are you sorrounding every single line with php tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :

```
<?php if (empty($x['item_name'])) : ?>
    <p>It's empty</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Not quite what I need. $x['item_name']

Answer (score 0):

try `empty()`

```
<?php echo (!empty($x['item_name']) ? $x['item_name'] : 'do this'); ?>
```

or

```
 if(!empty($x['item_name'])) {
    echo $x['item_name']; 
 }
 else {
    // do your stuff
 }
```

Comment: I think $x['item_name'] has a value of 0 so it thinks it is set, so it still echo's the content even though I dont have anything set for $x['item_name']

Comment: then try if($x['item_name'] != '') {